# Are there any tools could package some C++ class to C#?

Tags: c#, c++, class

One software SDK affords some APIs by C++ class library, including the h, lib, dll files.

However, I want to use C# to work with the library.

So,  are there any tools could package the C++ class library to C#? Or some suggestion?

I don't want use CLI, because of so many classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [C++/CLI](http://www.functionx.com/cppcli/index.htm), the dialect of C++ used in managed code   on the .NET platform.  The language was designed primarily for use in an application such as yours.

See this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/quickcppcli.aspx#A8) (the title is a bit of an exaggeration, but the content is good).  Other searches on wrappers for C++ code should give you more examples.

As Barry has pointed out, using a platform invoke (P/Invoke) call would let you call native code from a DLL.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to wrap the library manually, it's pretty straight forward to use [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI) to create a managed wrapper around your API or [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28VS.71%29.aspx) to call the native code directly from C#.

If you want to create a wrapper automatically, I believe the SWIG project has as a C/C++ => C# [module](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/CSharp.html). The SWIG module uses P/Invoke under the hood (so it is, the authors claim, useable on Mono as well). It appears to handle many of the details ([.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/04fy9ya1%28VS.90%29.aspx) and [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries)) of P/Invoke wrappers for you. I haven't used it, but it appears to be what you're looking for.

Comment: +1 SWiG is the way to "package up" an existing class for use from another language.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is build a COM wrapper around your C++ class library. Once the C++ classes are packaged as COM objects, you will be able to use them from your C# code.

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736(v=vs.71).aspx ("COM Interop Part 1: C# Client Tutorial")

If you need info on how to wrap C++ libraries into COM, I could suggest to read the excellent book "Inside COM" from Microsoft Press.